# rake deploy with permission denied when building Github blog

Tags: ruby, github, rake, octopress

I build Github blog based on `Octopress` and I have already added SSH key as Github's instruction. And when I test `ssh -T git@github.com` in git shell, it return successful result with

> Hi xxx, You're successfully authenicated ...

while when I run `rake deploy` in Ruby command, it will return `Permission denied (PublicKey)`

I have searched in Google and answers are always about wrong setting in SSH, but I don't know why `ssh -T` operation is successful in git shell if I set its wrong.

Please kindly give me some ways if you have ever met similar problem, thanks.

Comment: Is it failing on the connection, or are you doing anything else where it could be failing because of a public key?

Comment: when I run "ssh -T git@github.com" in ruby command, it returns Permission denied <publickey>. I am not sure why that happens because in git shell, it returns different result which is right